# How do I extract these numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of numbers that are of the form 000000xx or 00000yyy. There's a few thousand of these. I wish to extract the xx or yyy, but right would require the number of characters to be extracted. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

If your data is of the form:
*1234432566ABC*
or
*765257754322XY*
Then the last three characters are of the form:

*ABC*
or
*2XY*
We can determine if we should extract 2 or 3 characters by seeing if the first character of the trio is numeric or not:

```
=IF(ISERROR(--(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,3),1))),RIGHT(A1,3),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

The key trick is:

1. isolating the third character **from the right**
2. being able to test if it is a **numeral**

Answer (score 1):

```
=REPLACE(A1,1,SUM(--ISNUMBER(-LEFT(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)))))),"")
```

- `-ISNUMBER(…` returns a `1` for each numeric character in the string.
- `SUM(…` then adds those to return a count of the digits at the beginning of the string.
- We then `REPLACE` the `SUM` leading characters with a null string.

[image]

Comment: ...............clever...................................

Answer (score 0):

This should pull the *xx* or *yyy* off the right end so long as the whole thing is less than 99 characters in length.

```
=RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)-AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW($1:$99)/ISNUMBER(--MID(A2, ROW($1:$99), 1)), 1))
'alternate
=REPLACE(A2, 1, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW($1:$99)/ISNUMBER(--MID(A2, ROW($1:$99), 1)), 1), "")
```

Calculation efficiency could be improved if you change the two *99*'s to whatever the maximum number of digits to strip is.

Answer (score 0):

`A1` : 1234432566ABC

`A2` : 765257754322XY

`B1`, copied down :

```
=RIGHT(A1,ISERR(-LEFT(RIGHT(A1,3)))+2)
```

then,

`B1` return : `ABC`

`B2` return : `XY`